# Using array.map to return an typed array

Tags: typescript, object, types

I am writing an code to return an ApexAxisChartSeries but I can not figure what is wrong with my object. It does even say that "data" does not exist in type.

[image: Types of ApexSeries]
[image: Errors given]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it!

My biggest error is not taking some sleep, also I was not seeing the array at the end of the type definition.

[image: Fixed !]

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, you can accept your own answer so that this post can be marked as solved.